# react native navigation blank screen after using back button to close the app and reopen it

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation v6 this happens only when we press the android back button to exit the app and then reopen it. It needs to be closed completely to work correctly.

[image]

Comment: for ths your have to kill your app. our use can use AppState to detect apps state iD background, foreground or kill

Comment: I don't see a problem.  It's working as expected - the back button will minimize the app if no previous screen is detected. As mentioned above, if you want to kill the app - add logic to detect when the back button is pressed and programmatically close the app.